# how do I observe keyboard input event while the applicaion is not actived

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, keyboard-events

how do I observe keyboard input event while the  applicaion is not actived.

Comment: re Ghommeny: good idea. but I just want to user change song by hotkeys and without active my music app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a CGEventTap using [Quartz Event Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/). The user must have access for assistive devices turned on, which makes sense, because that's the only legitimate reason for you to do that.

If you want to set up a hotkey, there's an API in [Carbon Event Manager](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/) for that, and a Cocoa wrapper named SGHotKeysLib. Note that the Carbon Event Manager hotkey API is still supported in current, 64-bit Mac OS X.

Comment: `Carbon` ? is there new api sets in leapord

Comment: Carbon dates back to 10.0, as noted in the documentation. Most of it is deprecated and/or unavailable now, but some parts are not, and the Carbon Event Manager hotkey API is one of the parts that are still available and supported.

Comment: seems its the only way to handle event like this.

Comment: I know it's too late to answer this but right now i'd go with `NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:` google it, you'll get started.

Comment: @PedroVieira: It's not too late to answer it.