# How to install python-evdev on Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, wacom, evdev

Is there any way to install the `python-evdev` library on Mac OS? When I try to install it, Mac says that `The linux/input.h header file is missing.` (of course). Is it possible to install it under Mac? Or do you know any other alternative?

I have an application that reads the Wacom inputs in `/dev/input/wacom`, and it works great on Linux, but I'm trying to run it under Mac as well.

Comment: Consider mac ports and homebrew to help. Sometimes you do have to build the required libraries yourself, which is a pain.  Good exercise though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid that this isn't possible, since the evdev interface is specific to the Linux kernel. Even if you managed to install it, it would not work as there are no `/dev/input/*` devices from which events can be read on MacOS.

If you're looking for a portable solution, you may want to look into a library that abstracts event handling, such as [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348886/how-can-mac-os-x-games-receive-low-level-keyboard-input-events) also covers the options that you have for processing events in MacOS.